# simple http server for sending files in android via wifi

Tags: java, android, http

I am developing application which will send some files from one android device to an other device. One device will create a hot spot and will use the web browser to receive some files from the other device which will connect to the hot spot using WiFi. I do not known to much about HTTP. I have created simple sever in the sending device. The receiving device will connect to the server with its web browser. When i write the (IP:port number ) in the browser, it say "starting download" but the download does not finished. in the sending device i get IOException: sendto failed EPIPE (Broken pipe) .
my code is

```
boolean sending_done = false;
while (! sending_done)
{
    Socket socket = null;
    try
    {
       socket = serverSocket.accept();
       OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
       outputStream.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("Content-Type: application/zip\r\n".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=files.zip\r\n".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n".getBytes());
       outputStream.write("\r\n".getBytes());
       BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
       ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);
       zipOutputStream.setLevel(ZipOutputStream.STORED);
       sendFiles(zipOutputStream, to_send_files_array_list);

       byte[] CRLF ="\r\n".getBytes();
       writ_header(0, zipOutputStream, CRLF);
       zipOutputStream.write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.length);

       zipOutputStream.finish();
       zipOutputStream.flush();
       zipOutputStream.close();

       sending_done = true;

    }
    catch (IOException e)
   {
       e.printStackTrace();
       display_toast(e.toString());
   }
   finally
   {
       try
       {
          if (socket != null)
          {
              socket.close();
          }
       } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}


   private void sendFiles(ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream, ArrayList<File> filesToSend)
   {
      byte[] CRLF ="\r\n".getBytes();
      for(File file: filesToSend)
      {

          BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
          ZipEntry zipEntry = null;

         try
         {
              FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
              bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

              zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
              zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

              int x;
              byte[] buffer = new byte[buffer_size];
              while ((x= bufferedInputStream.read(buffer))!= -1)
              {
                  if (x>0)
                  {
                     writ_header(x, zipOutputStream, CRLF);
                     zipOutputStream.write(buffer,0,x);
                     zipOutputStream.write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.length);
                   }
              }
         }
        catch (IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally
       {
           try
           {
              if (zipEntry != null)
              {
                 zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
              }
              if (bufferedInputStream != null)
              {
                  bufferedInputStream.close();
              }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
    }
 }

 private void  writ_header(int length, OutputStream outputStream, byte[] CRLF) throws IOException
{
    byte[] header = Integer.toHexString(length).getBytes();
    outputStream.write(header, 0, header.length);
    outputStream.write(CRLF, 0, CRLF.length);
}
```

Comment: How about using ready-to-use libraries instead? Like SimpleFramework for HTTP server: http://www.simpleframework.org/

Comment: `sendFiles()`. Complex solution. You are zipping on the fly many files to one .zip file? Why so difficult? Just start with sending one ready .zip file from the file system.

Comment: Moreover in your explanation you are not talking about zipping at all.

Comment: `For sending you need an HTTP client library, not a server.`. Nonsense.

Comment: Please show the url you use in the browser. Does it end on .zip?

Comment: "For sending you need an HTTP client library, not a server." ????? I want to send files from one device to the web browser on the other device @Robert

Comment: I have used http://190.180.55.127:8070/files.zip and http://190.180.55.127:8070/files but both are not working. I think the browser closes the socket before the application start sending @greenapps

Comment: i also tried http://190.180.55.127:8070/ and it is not working @greenapps